# Unity3D build from Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, unity-game-engine, sandbox, gitlab-ci, unity3d-editor

I have been trying several ways of making an Unity3D build from an Ubuntu image by using a Gitlab CI container but seems to fail all the times (Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS).

I am getting the following error but I have not found useful information over there:

```
$ /opt/Unity/Editor/Unity -batchmode -nographics -silent-crashes -logFile ./unity.log -projectPath ./ -buildLinuxUniversalPlayer "./Build/linux/project" -quit
[0101/202644:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(161)] Running without the SUID sandbox! See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxSUIDSandboxDevelopment for more information on developing with the sandbox on.
```

That sandbox development is marked as deprecated, what am I missing here?.

Apart from that when I try to get the help of chrome-sandbox I get the following:

```
$ /opt/Unity/Editor/chrome-sandbox --help
The setuid sandbox provides API version 1, but you need 0
Please read https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxSUIDSandboxDevelopment.
close: Bad file descriptor
```

As I can see in the Unity Cloud Build platform they are using a MacOS system in order to build, do we have this alternative in GitLab CI (cloud service) ? Log line from Unity Cloud Build:

```
42:  + Building with Unity installed at /UNITY_PATH/Unity/Unity-2017_2_1f1/Unity.app/Contents/MacOS/Unity
```

Update:

I've added my gitlab-ci.yml:

```
image: ubuntu
before_script:
   - apt-get update
   - apt-get install wget < wget.txt
   - wget -q -O unity.deb http://beta.unity3d.com/download/fd37f3680b5f/unity-editor_amd64-2017.2.0b11.deb
   - ls -la
   - apt-get install gdebi < gdebi.txt
   - gdebi --n unity.deb
stages:
   - build
   - log
windows:
   stage: build
   script:
      - echo "Attempting to build for Windows"
      - /opt/Unity/Editor/Unity -batchmode -nographics -silent-crashes -logFile $(pwd)/unity.log -projectPath $(pwd) -buildWindowsPlayer "$(pwd)/Build/windows/GameTest.exe" -quit
macos:
   stage: build
   script:
      - echo "Attempting to build for OS X"
      - /opt/Unity/Editor/Unity -batchmode -nographics -silent-crashes -logFile $(pwd)/unity.log -projectPath $(pwd)-buildOSXUniversalPlayer "$(pwd)/Build/osx/GameTest.app" -quit
linux:
   stage: build
   script:
      - echo "Attempting to build for Linux"
      - /opt/Unity/Editor/Unity -batchmode -nographics -silent-crashes -logFile $(pwd)/unity.log -projectPath $(pwd) -buildLinuxUniversalPlayer "$(pwd)/Build/linux/GameTest" -quit
log:
   stage: log
   script:
      - echo 'Logs from build'
      - cat ./unity.log
```

Comment: can you share your gitlab-ci.yml ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed by Unity3D here [Unity3d Linux Releases](https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-on-linux-release-notes-and-known-issues.350256/page-2#post-3398912) this error is benign and it can be ignored, what was wrong in my case is that I was trying to use a Continuous Integration build with GitLab CI with a free account. This CI builds without GUI needs account activation and this feature is not included in the free version of Unity3D at this point.